# Want to display yesterdays date on jsp page

Tags: jsp, date

I need to display yesterdays date on a jsp page. I am currently displaying todays date.

```
<s:date name="new java.util.Date()" format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

Want to display yesterdays date, think it might be got by using -1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60*60*24*1000)
```

(Do not forget the import)

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find a better solution, so I use this:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>

<%
    Date now = new Date();
    Date yesterday = DateUtils.addDays(now, -1);
%>

<input type="text" value="<% out.print(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(yesterday)); %>">
```

- Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_handling_date.htm
- [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) class in [org.apache.commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)